# Too many SOQL queries error on apex class

Tags: apex, soql, class, list, insert

I have the class below getting data from a trigger (that seems to be working ok), the problem is, I am getting a "Too many SOQL queries" errors when it executes.  If I comment out "insert opptsToInsert;" then I have no problems, but of course my new opportunity is not created.  I've tried and regardless of where I put the insert I always get the same error. Any suggestions will be welcome.

```
public class RenewalOpportunities 
{
    public void CreateRenewalOpportunity(Map < Id, Opportunity > oldMap, Map < Id, Opportunity > newMap) 
    {
        System.debug('Renewal starting');    
        List < Opportunity > opptsToInsert = new List < Opportunity > ();
        Opportunity newOppt = new Opportunity();
        //List < Id > OpptyIds = new List < Id > ();
        for (Opportunity o: newMap.Values()) 
        {
            //OpptyIds.add(o.id);
            System.debug('Old ID ' + o.id);
            System.debug('Renewal check ' + o.RenewalCreated__c);

            {
                newOppt.Name = o.Name + ' Renewal Opportunity';
                newOppt.AccountId = o.AccountId;
                newOppt.RecordTypeId = o.RecordTypeId;
                newOppt.CloseDate = Date.Today() + 30;
                newOppt.StageName = 'Renewal Opportunity';
                newOppt.Type = 'Add-On Business';
                newOppt.NextStep = 'Send a invoice for maintenance renewal';
                 newOppt.OwnerId =o.OwnerId;}
                opptsToInsert.add(newOppt);
                System.debug('Account Name ' + newOppt.AccountId);
                System.debug('Opportunity Name ' + newOppt.Name);
                System.debug('Stage Name ' + newOppt.StageName);
                System.debug('Type Name ' + newOppt.Type);
                System.debug('Next Step ' + newOppt.NextStep);
                System.debug('Close Date ' + newOppt.CloseDate);
                System.debug('New Opportunities ' + opptsToInsert);


        }   

        System.debug('Size ' + opptsToInsert.size());
         if (opptsToInsert.size() > 0){ 
            insert opptsToInsert;}
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like every time an `Opportunity` is created, you create another `Opportunity`, which means you will have a recursive insert basically. You should be filtering the new records somehow. Can you clarify which trigger event you call this on?

Comment: Also note you have an extra set of curly brackets (`{}`) that act as an `Initialization Block` that will only run on your first loop iteration. See [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)

Comment: It sounds like one of your other triggers is broken. The code you have posted does not contain the source of this error.